# how to connect webservice with infopath2007 to submit and recive data in repeating table cotrol?

Tags: web-services, infopath-2007

I have situation to create the infopath 2007 form that must have the repeating table control. and user can view and submit the data to web service. I have built the webservice for that , which having the 2 methods. as saveData(parameters) and getData(). I know i have to create the data connections through Tool->data connection. but i still unable to get and submit data. what i have to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/sharepointinfopath/thread/48c3a7fa-1119-4d0f-ba1e-947490786ffa

If its not helping, please explain in detail, where you are facing the issue?